# Javascript Handlers

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

Can I have the following inside a form tag?

```
action="handler"
```

Is this legal? It supposedly runs a javascript function of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is legal but wont invoke javascript. It will submit the form to the server url specified by 'handler.'

Answer (score 2):

The `action` attribute is the URL the browser will submit the form to.

```
<form action="submitForm.php"><input /></form>
```

If you want to run JavaScript, you can make `handler` something like this:

```
<form action="javascript:myFunc(this)"><input /></form>
```

I highly suggest you don't do this, and instead use JavaScript event handlers to capture the `onsubmit` event.

```
<form id="myForm"><input /></form>

<script>
    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent the form the submitting.
                                // the form will only submit if
                                // it has an "action" attribute
        myFunc(this);
    });
</script>
```